# How to run homestead up

Tags: laravel, homestead

I try to run homestead up but I get vm: a box must be specified...
Screenshoot:
[image]

What is the problem here?

Also my project code is into D:/learninglaravel-5 so what I need to type into homestead.yaml file ?

I try everything but without success.
Please help me to start work with laravel - 2 days I try to run this homestead (is there some alternative to work- I have WAMP but also I cant run phpMYAdmin so I cant create database)!

Comment: Did you install vagrant?

Comment: yes offcource... several times I install vagrant...

Comment: as you can see I get message: vm: *A box must be specified

Comment: and did you get laravel/homestead?

Comment: vagrant box add laravel/homestead

Comment: yes, and then ask me to choose virtualbox and vmware_desktop and I choose 1)virtualbox, and then I wait about 20 min to download ...

Comment: please see: http://imgur.com/MdyiEF4

Comment: so nobody dont know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I am afraid you are not located at the homestead directory.

Comment: but when I run homestead command then I get list of aviabile commands ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CD in to your homestead directory and run `vagrant up`. You must be inside the homestead directory for any vagrant commands to be accepted

Read the full docs here
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

Comment: I try that but then I get messages: Warning. Connection timout. ... ... several times

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script for this because many people around me needed help with it. Maybe you can give it a try. Call it with git bash like: bash install_homestead after you placed it in a file named install_homestead in your user root directory.

Here's the script:

```
# Before you run this script: install Vagrant, VirtualBox VM, Git and Composer

# Remove Homestead if it is allready installed
rm -rf Homestead
rm -rf .homestead

cd VirtualBox\ VMs/
rm -rf homestead
cd ..

# Adding the vagrant box
vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

# Install Homestead
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
cd Homestead
bash init.sh

# Install dependencies
composer install

cd ../.ssh
rm -rf id_rsa*
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
cd ..

mkdir Code
cd Code
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel
cd ..

cd Homestead
homestead up
```

### Note:

Maybe it's not waterproof, I executed it for the last time a couple of months ago.

Comment: Great! Be sure you run the script in your user root directory (example: C:\Users\bobmarley), and that you have Vagrant, Virtualbox VM, Git and Composer installed.

Comment: I try as you tell me but now I have this: http://imgur.com/sF7mWQ9 - I have message: Coundn't open file .homestead/base

Comment: I try this: http://imgur.com/sF7mWQ9 but now I have message: Coundn't open file .homestead/base


I also change at vigrantfile - "base" to "laravel/homestead" but now I have: http://imgur.com/dx8nscV

Comment: I never run 'homestead up' in my .homestead folder. Isn't there a Homestead folder in your C:/Users/YourName ? Because in there you have to run 'homestead up'. Another thing: run 'composer install' in the .homestead folder (just like i did in the script)

Comment: Oh, and I personally never use vagrant commands. 'vagrant up' in a wrong directory will create a new box (I thought, not sure of that). By that way, Laravel Homestead docs of 4.2 differ from 5.1. In my opinion a bit weird, but maybe [that](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was my computer procesor... VM work only for I3,I5 ... not for Pentium